# Angular UI navber hidden when page change

Tags: angular-ui, navbar

when I change the page,in the first page has bottom navbar and in the second page do not has bottom navbar.When I from the second page the first page ,the bottom navbar is show ,but has nothing

```
<div class="navbar navbar-app navbar-absolute-top" ui-yield-to="headNavigation"
     ng-if='headNavigationShow' style="background: #C20404;padding-top:20px;height:65px;">
    <div class="btn-group pull-left" ui-yield-to="leftHeadNavigation">
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-center" ui-yield-to="centerHeadNavigation">
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group pull-right" ui-yield-to="rightHeadNavigation">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="navbar navbar-app navbar-absolute-bottom" ui-yield-to="footNavigation"
     ng-if='footNavigationShow'>
    <div class="btn-group pull-left" ui-yield-to="leftFootNavigation">
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-center" ui-yield-to="centerFootNavigation">
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group pull-right" ui-yield-to="rightFootNavigation">
    </div>
</div>

<!-- App Body -->
<div class="app-body">
    <div class="app-content" style="margin-top:13px;">
        <ng-view></ng-view>
    </div>
</div>
```

[this is the first page,it has the bottom navbar and has the menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejeKB.jpg)[this is first page ,back from the second page ,the bottom navbar has nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tD8Zg.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first page's bottom navbar has nothing ,because of the the bottom navbar has the. 
`<div ui-content-for="footNavigation" ng-if="$parent.headNavigationShow">
    <footnavigation-directive info="{{foot_navigation_position}}"
     </footnavigation-directive>
</div>`

like this use ng-if to contol the load order.